# Work Folders that include a shared group folder

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-share

I setup Work Folders on Server 2012 and everything is working. However, I do not know how to include a shared folder - like the default company folder - for each users Work Folder. Based on my understanding, each user creates its own separate user folder in the Work Folder and can only see files in that. How can I create a shared folder?

An example scenario to clarify:
A work folder is created at `E:\WF\` where UserA and UserB have permission to access it. UserA connects and now see's all the files located in `E:\WF\UserA`; likewise UserB connects and now sees all the files in `E:\WF\UserB`. A shared folder is also created at `E:\Shared\`.

How can I make the shared folder appear such as `E:\WF\UserA\Shared` and `E:\WF\UserB\Shared` so both have access to the same folder via Work Folders?

---

**Update: There is no provision to include shared files using Work Folders according to Microsoft so this is not possible.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend implementing something like that. You would create a redundant copy of this shared folder on every device. Either you need the data in this folder for collaboration, then an online share (mapped or redirected) is the better choice or if offline editing is important, people should copy the data into the personal WF. 
Workfolders is not very good at collaborating, what happens, when you use a "shared folder" you can see if you connect one user on several devices at once and start working on the same data (favorites or so). WF will try to keep up and the data dublicates with device IDs attached. Not nice.